# Unzip Interrupted

Tags: zip

I want to unzip a bunch of files.

The unzip process may get killed part of the way through.

I'd like to continue unzipping with, say `unzip -n`, but it seems as though if a file was only partially unzipped when unzip was killed then the file is completely skipped on the next run instead of being fully extracted as it should.

Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: What OS are you using? Most filemanagers on Unix/MacOS/Windows can go into a zip before extracting to allow copying only parts. Or extract within the filemanager.

Comment: I'm on Lubuntu 14.04. I want to extract the entire archive.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by:

> The unzip process may get killed part of the way through.

Do you know why this happens, or is it part of the problem finding out why this is happening?

If you are using **Linux/Unix**, you may want to run `unzip` using the `nohup` command, and that will prevent the process to get killed by a *"hang up"* signal.  Also, a good idea would be to redirect the output to a file, so you can review it later.  So, the full command to run will be something like this:

```
nohup unzip your_file > log.output 2>&1 &
```

If there's an error, it should get caught by the `2>&1` portion of the redirection (stdout and stderr).

Comment: `nohup` is a good idea; however, the user may also initiate the kill, which would lead to the same issue.